# WAN IP in 192.168 range

Tags: wan, network-access

hoping someone can help.

I am visiting family in Majorca and they have bought some cctv cameras that they would like set up so they can view the cams when back in the UK.

The problem I am running into is trying to route to the router so the cameras are available.

Effectively the internet is provided by a wireless provider through a transponder and connected to the router. The WAN ip address given is in the 192.168.1 range.

Is there any way of getting access to the cameras outside of the 192.168.0 range?

Comment: Any IP address in the `192.168.0.0/16` range is not routable on the Internet. Home networking is off-topic. You can ask this question on Super User.

Comment: Sounds like carrier grade NAT, if that helps you research it.

Comment: Only with the assistance of your ISP because you are being translated before your gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses guys, apologies that this was in the wrong section.
The isp gave me a static ip that 'could' change so its setup for now, hopefully it will not change to often :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set port forwarding on their router in majorca or connect to that router via VPN. if your royter does not support this, and most home grade routers don't, consider upgrading to [something like this](http://www.broadbandbuyer.co.uk/products/11946-d-link-dsr-250n/).

Also,be aware of the upload bandwidth available. use speedtest.net to confirm this. You will probably be restricted to SD resolution.

You can ask your ISP to upgrade your WAN IP to a fixed address, otherwise you will need to configure [dynamic dns](http://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-dynamic-dns/).

Comment: The carrier is giving the customer in Majorca a private address instead of a public address, so it is completely in the hands of the carrier, and there is nothing the ISP customer can do to rectify it.